# URL fileURLWithPath works in playground but doesn't work in a swift file

Tags: ios, swift, macos, tvos

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myaccout/Desktop/Demo.xml")
do {
   try fileURL.checkResourceIsReachable()
} catch {
    fatalError("The file cannot be found at the given path.")
}
```

This code work in the playground but doesn't work in a swift file.
I was running a breaking point test it s

> fileURL = URL <unavailable; try printing with "vo" or "po">

Could any one please tell me what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes this can be a problem with xcode not display it correctly on breakpoint. In other case (if i cant return something you waiting) - it nust show nil, but not message you wrote. Try to print it out using print(fileURL.absoluteString) to see if it has a value.

Comment: I tried it still doesn't work. It's still saying, `fileURL = URL <unavailable; try printing with "vo" or "po">`

Comment: Define "works" and "doesn't work"? Do you get into the `fataError()`? If that's the case, might want to check read the caught error?

Comment: did you add print(fileURL.absoluteString) to your code? because of message you wrote is xcode message, not swift code.

Comment: And as I see in your example - in playground you can have full rights for storage access, but not in ios - in ios you only limited by you app sandboxed access. Try something like this - if let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myaccout/Desktop/Demo.xml") { print(fileURL.absoluteString) }  and look in console what you will get here. You can set breakpoint to print statement inside if - and if it breaks - URL(fileURLWithPath - works ok.